# Python Script for Linux Syslog failed user login attemps with counters on unique IPs

Tags: python, syslog

I am attempting read from a syslog file and have the unique IPs that show up in the logs more than 10 times output into columns with the Unique IP and the hit count.

How can this be done?

so far I have the following:

```
fd=open('/var/log/login.log')
syslog = fd.readlines()
d = {}
for line in syslog:
data = line.split()
if len(data) >=15:
```

Sample syslog:

Jan 03 12:36:19 nix02 sshd[17643]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.9.28  user=root

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter